# HyperNext Android Creator and making Android apps

Tags: java, android

I've been trying to learn how to make Android apps and installed Eclipse and Android SDK but found it hard going as I'm not a programmer and only know a little Java. I then tried HyperNext Android Creator and found it much easier as it did have me creating some small apps quite quickly. Actually just modifying their projects and some tinkering to see how things work.

The problem is which is the best way to go as the whole Android scene is moving quickly and even App Inventor is no longer supported by Google. I wonder if there are any major changes coming with Android SDK that will prevent HAC working.  Perhaps Google will follow Apple and discourage non standard Android development tools? Any thoughts on the future of Android and developing for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am also using HAC but can't see any info on the their website about how it builds an Android app. I've just assumed that because it uses the Android SDK it is stable and will continue to work. However, in order to make a judgement we need to know the details of how it builds an Android app. Their HyperNext Studio apps for Windows and Mac seems to use a runtime engine for each platform that executes the apps code but I've seen no mention of this for Android.

Its hard to see Google restricting the languages used to develop Android apps as their Android culture is more open than Apple's iOS do and they need to get as many apps out to Market as possible. About Googles plans, perhaps someone can comment on this.

Comment: Thank you for the info about their HyperNext runtime engine approach. I asked a question on this in their forums and you were right about it. Unfortunately I don't understand the etiquette here for marking answers etc.